# how to use selectnode with a where clause in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have this xml:

```
<root>
<Player uID="2363">
<Name>Roy Mark</Name>
<Position>Goalee</Position>
<Stat Type="first_name">Roy</Stat>
<Stat Type="last_name">Mark</Stat>
<Stat Type="jersey_num">2</Stat>
</Player>
<Player uID="2343">
<Name>Steve Jack</Name>
<Position>Goalee</Position>
<Stat Type="first_name">Steve</Stat>
<Stat Type="last_name">Jack</Stat>
<Stat Type="jersey_num">7</Stat>
</Player>
<root>
```

I want to get the jersey_num of the the player with uID 2343.

What I am trying is:

```
$fileContents = [xml](gc Test.xml)
$temp1 = $fileContents.SelectNodes("/root/Player/Stat[@Type='jersey_num']").innerXML | where {$fileContents.root.Player.uID -eq "2343"}
```

And I am getting both the jersey numbers. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fileContents.SelectNodes('/root/Player[@uID="2343"]/Stat[@Type="jersey_num"]/text()')
```

Answer (score 1):

With your code, I'm thinking that you need to update this portion:

`where {$fileContents.root.Player.uID -eq "2343"}`

to:

`where {$_.root.Player.uID -eq "2343"}`

The $_ is a placeholder for the data being piped in from your command.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```powershell
$player = 2343
$fileContents.SelectNodes("//*[contains(concat(' ', @uID), $player)]//Stat") | where {$_.Type -eq "jersey_num"}
```